# Flash Video player subtitles

Tags: flash, subtitle

I want to insert subtitles in youtube flash movies. As I can see, there is a site that can do this. http://www.overstream.net/ is the site and I am wondering how I can do this?

If I make a flash player ang give it the url of a youtube video, it can play it?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will help you build a Flash application that will play Youtube videos:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html

Once you built that, simply add subtitles on top of that with delays in time with the video.